# Rendering component returned by HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

Normally the way to render the component returned by a Higher Order Component in React is to do (please tell me if I'm wrong, I'm quite new to React)

```
render() {
    const WrappedComponent = HOC(Component);
    return (
        <WrappedComponent ...props />
    )
}
```

But when I have to return a number of WrappedComponent with different props, is it possible to do it with the map function as you would normally do to return an array of WrappedComponent?

Comment: didn't quite get you... your HOC takes **one** component and returns an array of components ?

Comment: What I mean is, I want to do something like this, `{attributes.map(attribute => HOC(Component, attribute)}` to render an array of WrappedComponent. But this doesn't really work.

Comment: Should work if you're using React v16 or ^ ... otherwise render can't return arrays. What error is thrown ?

Comment: It does work with normal classes but not with a HOC, it doesn't actually give me any error, just nothing. So in my example given in the post, can you render the `HOC(Component)` without first assigning it to `WrappedComponent`?

Comment: are you sure you are returning a valid React element from the HOC ? Could you share your code ??

Comment: Ok it turns out I'm returning a class instead than an element. Thanks!